# Multilanguage with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, client-side, multilingual

I want to integrate i18n within a ReactJS application that renders on client-side only.

I can handle the internationalization itself with one of the several i18n libraries available, however I was wondering which would be the best way/available options to store whatever language the user has chosen cross-request (like refreshing the page).

Is this something I can handle on the client-side only or do I have to do it server-side and then pass it to the client?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have limited options with storing a users preference using client side technology.  Essentially, you are limited to storing these preferences in a cookie.

Any other sort of persisted data should be handled by the server and most likely saved to a database somewhere.